# Azure Active directory Add Assignment button greyed out

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group

I have an active directory application that is used as a service principle in DevOps pipelines. I need to assign **Directory Reader** role to this application. I am a Global Administrator, as shown in the picture below.

[image: Image showing my role]

When I try to assign a Directory reader role to the service user, the role assignment button is disabled as shown below. 
[image: PIcture showing role assignment button]

Is Global admin permission is not sufficient for this purpose or am I missing something here?

Comment: It should work, I recommend you to send a support ticket to Microsoft.

Comment: Besides global admin, what other role if assigned would allow this to be enabled? Said another way, what minimum role would someone need to be assigned in order to add remove users?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a "least privileged permission first" at play here.

You have Global Administrator & 2 other roles, remove yourself from these 2 other roles & try again.

Answer (score -1):

If you use PIM (Privileged Identity Management) then you can check if you can assign permissions there (you must be a member of the Privileged Role Administrator role).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-how-to-add-role-to-user