# As a Global administrator, I cannot a self-assignment in the Azure Portal (button greyed out)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently assigned the role of Global administrator in Azure. I assigned myself to the role Groups administrator. I would like to remove that role. However, that button is greyed out. I assume because I was able to assign the role to myself, I should be able to remove the role as well.

Currently there are no other Group administrators. However, it was like that before I assigned myself.

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767884/azure-active-directory-add-assignment-button-greyed-out) that asked about the same issue. However, there was no accepted answer.

Images showing the greyed out button:

- [My profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNVcD.png)
- [Group administrator's page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3KnZ.png)

Comment: Hi @kaisa did you try this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-how-to-add-role-to-user?tabs=new#update-or-remove-an-existing-role-assignment) process

Comment: I tried following the steps you mentioned, and yes it seems to be an issue or I can say not a clear way of assigning roles. 
Via AD role assignment or PIM account, the portal is allowing you to assign a role to yourself, but when you try to remove the same it throws error saying "You are not allowed to assign or make yourself eligible for a role."
I will be sharing this as a feedback with MS, lets see if they come back with some reply.

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentityRan We currently do not use Azure AD Privileged Identity Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, self-remove Azure AD roles is currently not supported. If you have any suggestions on this issue, you can submit your ideas or vote in the community. [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory)

There are similar problems [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39526).